# Class.forname throws Arrayindexoutofboundexception when trying to create object in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to create a object using **Class.forname** method but when I am calling it, I got the

> Arrayindexoutofboundexception

exception in the console.

I am loading few libraries from external path using argument

> -Dloader.path=/home/atul/ext_jars/

NOt sure what exactly the problem is, project compiles successfully and started.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the issue, as I said I have added few libraries externally. So one of the library which I created with different name, containing same class with same name and package etc.

So when **Class.forname** look for the class, it found 2 classes in the classpath, so throwing the exception related to **indexoutofbound**.

The fix is to remove the jar which contains same class. This will fix the issue. Need only one library in classpath which contains the class.